# Googlemap Marker from GeoPoint

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a Jar with geopoints, I use this bit of code to find the nearest city :

```
GetNService gn = new GetNService();
NGeoPoint nearest = gn.getN(lat, lon);
GeoPoint city = nearest.getPoint();
```

I would like to add a marker, but I don't know how to add with Geopoint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the lat and lang values from a `GeoPoint` like so

```
GetNService gn = new GetNService();
NGeoPoint nearest = gn.getN(lat, lon);
GeoPoint city = nearest.getPoint();

double lat = city.getLatitude();
double lon = city.getLongitude();
```

you can add a Marker like so

```
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
    .title("Marker Title"));
```

Comment: the lat and lng are for the current location.

Comment: Glad to help, and if this answer was helpful to you, please mark it as accepted :-) Happy coding! @daviddev38

Comment: Just for curiosity, is it possible to have the 5 nearest cities?

Comment: @daviddev38 That's a good question! I suggest that you open a new question for that. And try to give as much details as possible, then it's a higher chance of getting an answer.